# html5 msie javascript getting DOM processing to work in MSIE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, dom

I'm having a problem getting simple HTML5 DOM processing to work on MSIE 9. It works without a DOCTYPE tag. But with the inclusion of DOCTYPE html (indicating html5), MSIE 9 doesn't process it. Is there another way that I can do this so that it works as html5?

The code attempts to create a nodeList by getting a DOM node and getting elements from that by tag name. The simple test is to display the nodeList.length. This is a small sample of what I see as a larger problem in the application I'm building. But this small bit of code is better to present here, I think, than trying to show you my whole application.

The following code works on Chrome, Firefox, Opera and likely more ... but not on MSIE 9. I also have it online, so you can just click [this link](http://isr.servequake.com:8080/MopDel/displayListTest2.htm) (as long as I'm running) and try it; then copy the address to try it in other browsers. I've also removed "<!DOCTYPE html>" and it then works in MSIE. But then no browser will know that it's html5 (if I understand it correctly).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setOptions () {

  var ndiv = document.getElementById("products");
  var OptionList = ndiv.getElementsByTagName("option");

 document.getElementById("dump").innerHTML = "OptionList.length " + OptionList.length;

}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="setOptions()">
<br/><br/><br/>
<div id="dump"></div>
<div id="products" style="display:none">
  <option>MOTOR</option>
  <option>CHASSI</option>
  <option>ELECTRIC</option>
  <option>BRAKES</option>
  <option>TIRES</option>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked that IE9 supports what you're trying to do? IE doesn't have the greatest reputation for being current.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will fix your problem, but it would be worth fixing errors you have in your markup first. Use a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/). Btw, the namespace declaration [is not needed](http://diveintohtml5.info/semantics.html). `<html lang="en">` will do.

Comment: jbabey: You're right about IE's reputation. When I'm working on the browser side, not a day goes by when I don't swear a bit at MS. Info on the web is mixed ... with MS giving tutorials based on the standard and some comparison charts saying IE supports up to 100% of HTML5 as far back as version 7. It makes for a lot of time consuming effort, effectively requiring full tests for compatibility on every little thing.

Comment: Ivan: Why would lang="en" make a difference? I'm using extended latin.

Comment: @Roger F. Gay I'm just saying the namespace declaration is not required when using HTML5. It's still a good idea to declare what language you are using. As I understand, The `lang` attribute refers to the language of the page, rather than character set specifically. If the contents of the page are written in Latin you can use `lang="la"`.

Comment: I've used that in xml, I think (certainly related) in support of internationalization. Since we're referring to content language rather than the charset, I'm actually building lang="sv". Since you mentioned that it's a good idea, I googled and quickly realized it helps search engines ... so people preferring a particular language can easily find it. So, even though I'm not internationalizing the code just now, it's still a good idea. Missed it because searching using keywords in the language usually gives appropriate results. Thanks for noticing. I've added it to my real page.

Comment: @Ivan Just realized that it also reduces the work required by search engines. So, by including the lang attribute, we're helping make the whole WWW more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re using invalid markup. Option elements should not be children of div elements. If you change the div element with ID of products to be a select element instead, it will work as expected.

As IE9 doesn't have an HTML5 parser, you can not guarantee what will happen with invalid markup, and unexpected results like this may happen. IE10 has an HTML5 parser, so handles the error case in line with other browsers.

Comment: Thank you. That does indeed work as you describe. There's some confusion in the info available on the web re: MSIE versions and HTML5, although enough digging and your clear answer isn't too much of a surprise. Looks like I can be careful and test and probably cover at least MSIE 9. As a follow up (maybe I'll post another question); I'm wondering where (which MSIE version) I should set my test to force installation of Chrome Frame or use another browser.

Comment: IE8 and earlier has been suggested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742663/use-edge-or-ie9-for-x-ua-compatible-header/8869331#8869331  I have IE9 on my dev machine, so I can test in that with and without Frame. So, that'll probably work for me.

Comment: I’m personally not a fan of using Chrome Frame. If you can get it working natively in IE then you should probably go that route. IE9 you certainly shouldn’t need to use Chrome Frame. It is possible IE8 wont give you trouble too, unless you’re relying on more recent features. It should be a decision on a case by case basis.

Comment: I'm now using html5 datalist. I haven't had a chance to test it on ie10 yet, but it's not supported in 9 or below. For IE, I replace the box with a comment and link to the MSIE section on my help page, advising users of their alternatives if they want to use advanced features. I decided this is the most polite way to go; not forcing users to a download page ... not even a popup ... and they can even use the site without the datalist feature if they want to. Meta data is set to use best available, GCF if they have it. I assume it will work in IE10 because MS says so.